# GREP fails to find the mount point of my device in bash script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, debian

Need less to say after reading this, I am a newie. The code:

```
#!/bin/bash
IBL=`blkid |grep "deviceLabel" | awk '{print $1}'`
BSHOW="echo ${IBL::-1}"
```

seems to work; however, when I do this:

```
SP_CHECK=`df -h | grep ${BSHOW}`
echo "this is SP_CHECK= ${SP_CHECK}
```

sp shows nothing. Any idea why? any pointers to what topic I can look at to learn better?

Comment: Please show the output of `blkid`

Comment: Replace `BSHOW="echo ${IBL::-1}"` by `BSHOW="${IBL::-1}"`.

Comment: /dev/sr0: UUID="2016-04-28-..." LABEL="VBOXADDITIONS" TYPE="iso19966"
/dev/sdc1: UUID="2016-04-28-..." LABEL="VBOXADDITIONS" TYPE="iso19966"
/dev/sdb1: UUID="2016-04-28-..." LABEL="VBOXADDITIONS" TYPE="iso19966"
/dev/sda1: UUID="2016-04-28-..." LABEL="VBOXADDITIONS" TYPE="iso19966"
/dev/sda1: UUID="2016-04-28-..." LABEL="VBOXADDITIONS" TYPE="iso19966"

Comment: When I replace echo I get "line 10: /dev/sdc1: Permission Denied".
I am the root user

Comment: @SentryViewSys It sounds like you used backticks around it instead of double quotes.

Comment: @SentryViewSys Put the output in the question so you can format it readably.

Comment: @Barmar where did I use the backticks? NVM, it worked.... thank you!

Comment: If you put backticks around `${IBL::-1}` instead of double quotes, it will try to execute `/dev/sdc1` as a command.